# "Sorry, something went wrong" during execution of custom Web part on 2013

Tags: 2013, web-part, error, custom

I have a custom webpart in SP 2013 environment over Amazon. This webpart reads a `xml` file, loads the contents to the `SQL Database` and then reads the contents from Database and create discussions in a new Community site (again, created by webpart code). On my DEV environment which a single server farm with SQL(2012) on a separate box, the code works fine.

But when i run the code on my TEST and PROD environments, the code starts as expected. It creates community site, loads `xml` data to SQL tables and starts creating discussions. But, after creating around 20-40 discussions it gives following error,
[image]

The TEST environment have 2 load balanced FE, one APP server, one DC, one ADFS server and one DB server. We are using PING as a `Trusted identity provider` on TEST and PROD, but not on DEV.

I am executing the page from a browser on one of the FE servers.

I get following corresponding entries on the SharePoint LOG files,

```
03/05/2015 06:23:53.98  w3wp.exe (0x107C)                           0x18EC  SharePoint Portal Server        Communities                     aa797   Monitorable DiscussionListCommunityEventHandler.HandleEvent: begin  d3c7ef9c-3c99-d059-fdcf-f12ec2e06ad1
03/05/2015 06:23:54.04  w3wp.exe (0x107C)                           0x18EC  SharePoint Portal Server        Communities                     aa8ac   Monitorable DiscussionListCommunityEventHandler.HandleEvent: success    d3c7ef9c-3c99-d059-fdcf-f12ec2e06ad1
03/05/2015 06:23:54.04  w3wp.exe (0x107C)                           0x18EC  SharePoint Portal Server        Communities                     al3jg   Monitorable CategoriesListCommunityEventHandler.HandleEvent: begin  d3c7ef9c-3c99-d059-fdcf-f12ec2e06ad1
03/05/2015 06:23:54.07  w3wp.exe (0x107C)                           0x18EC  SharePoint Portal Server        Communities                     al3jj   Monitorable CategoriesListCommunityEventHandler.HandleEvent: success    d3c7ef9c-3c99-d059-fdcf-f12ec2e06ad1
03/05/2015 06:23:54.07  w3wp.exe (0x107C)                           0x18EC  SharePoint Portal Server        Communities                     aa8ae   Monitorable ReputationCommunityEventHandler.HandleEvent: begin  d3c7ef9c-3c99-d059-fdcf-f12ec2e06ad1
03/05/2015 06:23:54.09  w3wp.exe (0x107C)                           0x18EC  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    High        Leaving Monitored Scope (EnsureListItemsData). Execution Time=21.054048 d3c7ef9c-3c99-d059-fdcf-f12ec2e06ad1
03/05/2015 06:23:54.09  w3wp.exe (0x107C)                           0x18EC  SharePoint Portal Server        Communities                     al3jd   Monitorable CommunityNotificationsEventHandler.HandleEvent: begin   d3c7ef9c-3c99-d059-fdcf-f12ec2e06ad1
03/05/2015 06:23:54.12  w3wp.exe (0x107C)                           0x18EC  SharePoint Portal Server        Communities                     al3jf   Monitorable CommunityNotificationsEventHandler.HandleEvent: success d3c7ef9c-3c99-d059-fdcf-f12ec2e06ad1
03/05/2015 06:23:54.40  w3wp.exe (0x107C)                           0x124C  SharePoint Foundation           Database                        ahjqp   High        [Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 03/05/2015 06:23:53.98, Original Level: Verbose] SQL connection time: 0.05992 for Data Source=SPTSTSQLServer01;Initial Catalog=WSS_Content_Share;Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Connect Timeout=15;Application Name=SharePoint[w3wp][2][WSS_Content_Share]   d3c7ef9c-3c99-d059-fdcf-f12ec2e06ad1
03/05/2015 06:23:54.40  w3wp.exe (0x107C)                           0x124C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    High        Leaving Monitored Scope (EnsureListItemsData). Execution Time=425.786224    d3c7ef9c-3c99-d059-fdcf-f12ec2e06ad1
03/05/2015 06:23:54.40  w3wp.exe (0x107C)                           0x124C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         al3j4   Monitorable SPUtility.CreateNewDiscussionReply: begin   d3c7ef9c-3c99-d059-fdcf-f12ec2e06ad1
03/05/2015 06:23:54.42  w3wp.exe (0x107C)                           0x124C  SharePoint Foundation           Database                        fa45    High        System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.get_ConnectionString()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.OnPreExecuteCommand(SqlCommand command)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior, SqlQueryData monitoringData, Boolean retryForDeadLock)   d3c7ef9c-3c99-d059-fdcf-f12ec2e06ad1
03/05/2015 06:23:54.42  w3wp.exe (0x107C)                           0x124C  SharePoint Foundation           Database                        fa46    High           at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.ExecuteQueryInternal(Boolean retryfordeadlock)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.ExecuteQuery(Boolean retryfordeadlock)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetListItemDataWithCallback2(IListItemSqlClient pSqlClient, String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrViewName, String bstrViewXml, SAFEARRAYFLAGS fSafeArrayFlags, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pSACallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingCallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingPrevCallback, ISPDataCallback pFilterLinkCallback, ISPDataCallback pSchemaCallback, ISPDataCallback pRowCountCallback, Boolean& pbMaximalView)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetListItemDataWithCallback2(IListItemSqlClient pSqlClient, String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrViewNa... d3c7ef9c-3c99-d059-fdcf-f12ec2e06ad1
03/05/2015 06:23:54.42* w3wp.exe (0x107C)                           0x124C  SharePoint Foundation           Database                        fa46    High        ...me, String bstrViewXml, SAFEARRAYFLAGS fSafeArrayFlags, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pSACallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingCallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingPrevCallback, ISPDataCallback pFilterLinkCallback, ISPDataCallback pSchemaCallback, ISPDataCallback pRowCountCallback, Boolean& pbMaximalView)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetListItemDataWithCallback2(IListItemSqlClient pSqlClient, String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrViewName, String bstrViewXml, SAFEARRAYFLAGS fSafeArrayFlags, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pSACallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingCallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingPrevCallback, ISPDataCallback pFilterLinkCallback, ISPDataCallback pSchemaCallback, ISPDataCallback pRowCountCallback, Boolean& pbMaximalView)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.EnsureListIte...  d3c7ef9c-3c99-d059-fdcf-f12ec2e06ad1
03/05/2015 06:23:54.42* w3wp.exe (0x107C)                           0x124C  SharePoint Foundation           Database                        fa46    High        ...msData()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.GetItemIndexById(Int32 id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.EnsureItemIsValid()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.GetValue(SPField fld, Int32 columnNumber, Boolean bRaw, Boolean bThrowException)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.GetValue(String strName, Boolean bThrowIfValueMissing, Boolean bThrowIfFieldMissing)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.CreateNewDiscussionReply(SPListItem parent)     at JiveContentMigration.JiveContentMigrationWebpart.JiveContentMigrationWebpartUserControl.associateAllRepliesToDiscussion(SPListItem newSPDiscusion, String jiveDiscussionID, SPList imgLibrary)     at JiveContentMigration.JiveContentMigrationWebpart.JiveContentMigrationWebpartUserControl.createDiscussions()     at ...  d3c7ef9c-3c99-d059-fdcf-f12ec2e06ad1
03/05/2015 06:23:54.43  w3wp.exe (0x107C)                           0x124C  SharePoint Foundation           Database                        aek90   High        SecurityOnOperationCheck = True d3c7ef9c-3c99-d059-fdcf-f12ec2e06ad1
03/05/2015 06:23:54.43  w3wp.exe (0x107C)                           0x124C  SharePoint Foundation           Database                        btq8    High        System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.get_ConnectionString()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.OnPreExecuteCommand(SqlCommand command)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior, SqlQueryData monitoringData, Boolean retryForDeadLock)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.ExecuteQueryInternal(Boolean retryfordeadlock)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.ExecuteQuery(Boolean retryfordeadlock) d3c7ef9c-3c99-d059-fdcf-f12ec2e06ad1
03/05/2015 06:23:54.43  w3wp.exe (0x107C)                           0x124C  SharePoint Foundation           Database                        ad194   High        ExecuteQuery failed with original error 0x80131530  d3c7ef9c-3c99-d059-fdcf-f12ec2e06ad1
03/05/2015 06:23:54.43  w3wp.exe (0x107C)                           0x124C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         xxpm    High        Unable to execute query: Error 0x80131530   d3c7ef9c-3c99-d059-fdcf-f12ec2e06ad1
03/05/2015 06:23:54.43  w3wp.exe (0x107C)                           0x124C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8e2s    Medium      Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80131530  d3c7ef9c-3c99-d059-fdcf-f12ec2e06ad1
03/05/2015 06:23:54.43  w3wp.exe (0x107C)                           0x18EC  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   ajk39   Medium      UserProfileDBCache_WCFLogging::Begin ProfileDBCacheServiceClient.GetUserData.ExecuteOnChannel   d3c7ef9c-3c99-d059-fdcf-f12ec2e06ad1
03/05/2015 06:23:54.43  w3wp.exe (0x107C)                           0x18EC  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   ajk35   Medium      MossClientBase_WCFLogging::Begin MossClientBase.ExecuteOnChannel    d3c7ef9c-3c99-d059-fdcf-f12ec2e06ad1
03/05/2015 06:23:54.43  w3wp.exe (0x107C)                           0x18EC  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   ajk36   Medium      MossClientBase_WCFLogging:: MossClientBase.ExecuteOnChannel -  Executing codeblock on channel   d3c7ef9c-3c99-d059-fdcf-f12ec2e06ad1
03/05/2015 06:23:54.43  w3wp.exe (0x107C)                           0x18EC  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        e5mc    Medium      WcfSendRequest: RemoteAddress: 'http://sptst02:32843/19b4b168d5d94364927b17d33af9d7b4/ProfileDBCacheService.svc' Channel: 'Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.IProfileDBCacheService' Action: 'http://Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles/GetUserData' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:4894721d-2832-49ef-9525-35c3b1b34492'    d3c7ef9c-3c99-d059-fdcf-f12ec2e06ad1
03/05/2015 06:23:54.45  w3wp.exe (0x107C)                           0x18EC  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   ajk37   Medium      MossClientBase_WCFLogging:: MossClientBase.ExecuteOnChannel -  Executed codeblock on channel    d3c7ef9c-3c99-d059-fdcf-f12ec2e06ad1
03/05/2015 06:23:54.45  w3wp.exe (0x107C)                           0x18EC  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   ajk4a   Medium      UserProfileDBCache_WCFLogging::End ProfileDBCacheServiceClient.GetUserData.ExecuteOnChannel d3c7ef9c-3c99-d059-fdcf-f12ec2e06ad1
03/05/2015 06:23:54.45  w3wp.exe (0x107C)                           0x18EC  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    High        Leaving Monitored Scope (CommunityEventReceiver::HandleEvent). Execution Time=538.769216    d3c7ef9c-3c99-d059-fdcf-f12ec2e06ad1
03/05/2015 06:23:54.45  w3wp.exe (0x107C)                           0x18EC  SharePoint Foundation           Dev Events                      ajbpn   Medium      Set EventFiringDisabled to [False].  Stack trace: [   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.CommunityEventReceiver.HandleEvent(SPItemEventProperties properties)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.CommunityEventReceiver.ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventManager.RunItemEventReceiver(SPItemEventReceiver receiver, SPUserCodeInfo userCodeInfo, SPItemEventProperties properties, SPEventContext context, String receiverData)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventManager.RunItemEventReceiverHelper(Object receiver, SPUserCodeInfo userCodeInfo, Object properties, SPEventContext context, String receiverData)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventManager.<>c__DisplayClassa`1.<InvokeEventReceiver>b__7()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunAsUser(SPUserToken userToken... d3c7ef9c-3c99-d059-fdcf-f12ec2e06ad1
03/05/2015 06:23:54.45* w3wp.exe (0x107C)                           0x18EC  SharePoint Foundation           Dev Events                      ajbpn   Medium      ..., Boolean bResetContext, WaitCallback code, Object param)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventManager.InvokeEventReceiver[ReceiverType](SPUserToken userToken, Guid tranLockerId, RunEventReceiver runEventReceiver, Object receivers, Int32 n, Object properties, SPEventReceiverOperationsType operationsType, Boolean& canceled, String& error)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventManager.InvokeEventReceivers[ReceiverType](SPRemoteEventReceiverCallType remoteCallType, SPUserToken userToken, Guid tranLockerId, RunEventReceiver runEventReceiver, RunRemoteEventReceiver runRemoteEventReceiver, Object receivers, Object properties, Boolean checkCancel, SPEventReceiverOperationsType operationsType)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventManager.InvokeEventReceivers[ReceiverType](SPRemoteEventReceiverCallType re...  d3c7ef9c-3c99-d059-fdcf-f12ec2e06ad1
03/05/2015 06:23:54.45* w3wp.exe (0x107C)                           0x18EC  SharePoint Foundation           Dev Events                      ajbpn   Medium      ...moteCallType, Byte[] userTokenBytes, Guid tranLockerId, RunEventReceiver runEventReceiver, RunRemoteEventReceiver runRemoteEventReceiver, Object receivers, Object properties, Boolean checkCancel, SPEventReceiverOperationsType operationsType)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventManager.HandleEventCallback[ReceiverType,PropertiesType](Object callbackData)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPThreadPool.WaitCallbackWrapper(Object state)     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threa...  d3c7ef9c-3c99-d059-fdcf-f12ec2e06ad1
03/05/2015 06:23:54.45* w3wp.exe (0x107C)                           0x18EC  SharePoint Foundation           Dev Events                      ajbpn   Medium      ...ding.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()     at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()  ] d3c7ef9c-3c99-d059-fdcf-f12ec2e06ad1
03/05/2015 06:23:54.45  w3wp.exe (0x107C)                           0x18EC  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    High        Leaving Monitored Scope (Event Receiver (Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c, Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.CommunityEventReceiver)). Execution Time=541.011328   d3c7ef9c-3c99-d059-fdcf-f12ec2e06ad1
03/05/2015 06:23:54.45  w3wp.exe (0x107C)                           0x18EC  SharePoint Foundation           Performance                     nask    Monitorable An SPRequest object was not disposed before the end of this thread.  To avoid wasting system resources, dispose of this object or its parent (such as an SPSite or SPWeb) as soon as you are done using it.  This object will now be disposed.  Allocation Id: {1025DF23-8B95-4787-A5CC-0C55DCBD0464}  To determine where this object was allocated, set Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService.ContentService.CollectSPRequestAllocationCallStacks = true.    
03/05/2015 06:23:54.46  w3wp.exe (0x107C)                           0x124C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8nca    Medium      Application error when access /JMTS/SitePages/Migratecontent.aspx, Error=Request timed out. d3c7ef9c-3c99-d059-fdcf-f12ec2e06ad1
03/05/2015 06:23:54.46  w3wp.exe (0x107C)                           0x124C  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  System.Web.HttpException: Request timed out.    d3c7ef9c-3c99-d059-fdcf-f12ec2e06ad1
03/05/2015 06:23:54.46  w3wp.exe (0x107C)                           0x124C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ajlz0   High        Getting Error Message for Exception System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Request timed out.   d3c7ef9c-3c99-d059-fdcf-f12ec2e06ad1
03/05/2015 06:23:54.51  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1520)                       0x13B0  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      aeh57   Medium      Sql Ring buffer status eventsPerSec = ,processingTime=0,totalEventsProcessed=0,eventCount=0,droppedCount=0,memoryUsed=0  
03/05/2015 06:23:54.53  w3wp.exe (0x107C)                           0x124C  SharePoint Foundation           Upgrade                         aiaih   High        [Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: Verbose] desiredVersion: {0}    d3c7ef9c-3c99-d059-fdcf-f12ec2e06ad1
03/05/2015 06:23:54.54  w3wp.exe (0x107C)                           0x124C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         aat87   Monitorable     d3c7ef9c-3c99-d059-fdcf-f12ec2e06ad1
```

On the Event Viewer on the FE server, i can see a lot of 6398 error ,

```
The Execute method of job definition Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.PersistedNavigationTermSetSyncJobDefinition (ID 6103e3e5-5fc2-49a7-b945-e5d39831d2ca) threw an exception. More information is included below.

The HTTP service located at http://localhost:32843/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/securitytoken.svc/actas is unavailable.  This could be because the service is too busy or because no endpoint was found listening at the specified address. Please ensure that the address is correct and try accessing the service again later.
```

Any help will be greatly appriciated.

Comment: What if you run your code asynchronously instead of waiting for 60-120 seconds for the web part to finish? Just display a message: "Thank you!" Your discussions are being created, bla, bla, bla. It might take a few minutes"

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the webpart is just taking too long so the page is timing out.  How long does it take on dev?  90 seconds or more?

Typically on a dev environment especially when debugging, the timeouts are adjusted to the max so that the page doesn't timeout while stepping through the code.

Maybe try adjusted the standard page timeout in your test environment and see if it helps.  A value of 300 is equal to 5 minutes:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200" executionTimeout="300" />
```

Or you can try wrapping your code in an [SPLongOperation msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splongoperation.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

You may need to set `debug="false"` on `<compilation />` tag in addition to `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200" executionTimeout="300" />`.

Based on where your page exists, you may also need to make same changes to web.config file in "_layouts" folder as well.

Comment: It depends on the size of data. On DEV it took around 20 min. for the same data and was not in debugging mode. I will try your suggestion and revert back.

Comment: This didn't seems to make a difference......same error even after wrapping my code in SPLongOperation. Could it be some configuration differences in the environment ?

Comment: I'm wondering if it's just taking too long.  20 minutes is a long time for a webpage to run.  Maybe you should change your design.  Maybe the webpart should start a timer job which then creates the discussions.  Timer jobs can run for hours if needed.  You can also construct your timer job to send the % complete which your webpart could read and display as kind of a progress bar or something if you wanted.